# Выполнение php по таймеру Javascript

Tags: таймер, ajax, php, javascript

Собственно есть скрипт `http://сайт.ru/gr.php` возможно ли например на странице `http://сайт.ru/1.html` вставить Javascript который если страница загружена в браузере будет через каждых 5 минут выполнять и выводить результат выполнения ПХП скрипта...

Если возможно, то, как это сделать? Дело в том, что в Javascript я полный ноль... и даже приблизительно не знаю, как такое реализовать!

P.S: никакие данные передавать скрипту не нужно, просто выполнить скрипт (как будто просто кто-то загрузил адрес http://сайт.ru/gr.php в браузере).

Comment: Осваивайте AJAX и setTimeout. Это проще, чем кажется на первый взгляд.

Comment: решил проблему проще, вставил в начале страницы скрипт перефреша

<script>
function fresh() {
location.reload();
}
setInterval("fresh()",30000);
</script>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    function AjaxContent() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/url/',
            data: {'some':'data'},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                Timer()
            }
        })
    }

    function Timer() {
        setTimeout('AjaxContent()', 5*1000*60);
    }

    Timer();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

> решил проблему проще, вставил в начале
> страницы скрипт перефреша

```
<script> function fresh() {
location.reload(); }
setInterval("fresh()",30000);
</script>
```

Здесь не нужен интервал. При релоаде все равно все пропадет, так что используйте таймаут, как посоветовали.